# Is there a Sandbox available for Kaa IoT 0.10.1 or 0.11.0?

Tags: kaa

The Kaa IoT website shows that the current available sandbox has Kaa version 0.10.0. Since there are some bugs (https://jira.kaaproject.org/browse/KAA-1087) which have been fixed in the subsequent versions of Kaa, I wanted to know if the next versions i.e. 0.10.1 or 0.11.0 are available for the Sandbox.

Answer (score 0):

Nope, these two versions (0.10.1 or 0.11.0) aren't officially released. Instead you can compile source code which milestone is 0.11.0 and install kaa in a single linux node envirorment.